# Non-Interface methods

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class

I have been reading up on programing to interfaces rather than implementation. One area I am not properly understanding is how to deal with non-interface methods. For example an interface IAnimal and a Cat class that implements it. My examples are in C# but I think it should also apply to other languages.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Eat();

}

    public class Cat : IAnimal
    {

    public Cat()

    public void Eat()
    { 
         //Do something
    }


    public string Meow()
    {
        return "meow";
    }

}
```

From what I've read it seems like I should be trying to work with the interface rather than the cat implementation such as,

```
Main()
{
    IAnimal cat = new Cat();
}
```

But this leaves me without access to my meow method as it is not a part of the IAnimal interface. Should I be creating another interface ICat which implements IAnimals and have Cat implement it? And does this mean that all methods should be an implementation from an interface or abstract class? Or am I doing something else here wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you add a more general method to the interface maybe `string speak()`.? Then whichever class implements it can have its own message.

Comment: What about class fish which can't speak at all?

Comment: Then it can return an empty string. Or an indicator that there is no sound.

Comment: Or the animals that can speak could implement `ITalkingAnimal`.

Comment: So from the comments it sounds like you are advocating to include all methods in a related interface and not leave any such as in the example?

Comment: try to use the 'as' reserved key to treat the element as another cat as Cat

Comment: What about an interface like this: `IViralAnimalOnYouTube`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is you is have another interface that represent's speaking animals and either inherit from IAnimal or add it as a 2nd interface. Classes that have animals that speak implement the 2nd interface.

with a inherited interface.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Eat();
}

public interface ISpeakingAnimal : IAnimal
{
    string Speak();
}

public class Cat : ISpeakingAnimal 
{
    public Cat()

    public void Eat()
    { 
         //Do something
    }


    public string Speak()
    {
        return "meow";
    }
}

public class Fish : IAnimal 
{
    public Fish()

    public void Eat()
    { 
         //Do something
    }
}
```

With a 2nd decorator interface

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Eat();
}

public interface ISpeakable
{
    string Speak();
}

public class Cat : IAnimal, ISpeakable
{
    public Cat()

    public void Eat()
    { 
         //Do something
    }

    public string Speak()
    {
        return "meow";
    }
}

public class Fish : IAnimal 
{
    public Fish()

    public void Eat()
    { 
         //Do something
    }
}
```

If you need the method not be `Speak()` but instead be `Meow()` you can use explicit interface implementations to expose the `Speak()` method only though that interface.

```
public class Cat : ISpeakingAnimal 
{
    public Cat()

    public void Eat()
    { 
         //Do something
    }


    string ISpeakingAnimal.Speak()
    {
        return Meow();
    }

    public string Meow()
    {
        return "meow";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a general rule of thumb on when to implement multiple interfaces vs chaining the interfaces?

Comment: Depends on how you plan on using it. For your example in your question you would use the interitance. If you had code like `IEnumerable<string> MakeThemSpeak(IEnumerable<...> obj)` you would likely use `ISpeakable` so if you had things that could speak but where not an animal it could use it (for example maybe you had a `IRobot` too).

Comment: Ok, and confirming then you're saying that all methods should be implemented from an interface somewhere?

Comment: You follow a pattern where it makes sense, some places it does not make sense. For example a DTO object that has properties and no methods does not make sense to have a interface for.

Answer (score 1):

The point of an interface is to define behavior common to classes that implement that interface. You are correct in noting that defining cat like so:

```
    IAnimal cat = new Cat();
```

leaves you unable to access methods in the Cat class that are not in IAnimal. So why is it encouraged to implement things in this way?

The answer is simple: it makes it very easy to change the code later on. For example, if we have a Dog class that implements IAnimal, like so:

```
    public class Dog : IAnimal
    {
        // some methods
    }
```

then we can very easily replace our Cat class with the Dog class, without having to change any other code. In other words, we can replace:

```
    IAnimal cat = new Cat();
```

with

```
    IAnimal dog = new Dog();
```

without having to change **any** other code in the entire program (besides the variable names). This is because defining Cat and Dog with respect to IAnimal forces them to only use methods found within IAnimal, though they may be implemented differently in Cat and Dog.

Of course, if you want to use something specific only to Cat or Dog, you will have to define the class explicitly, as mentioned by @Erick in his answer, like so:

```
    Cat cat = new Cat();
```

In general, you should try to define as many common behaviors in the interface as possible, only explicitly casting to a certain class like Cat or Dog when absolutely necessary. This makes your code a lot more versatile and changeable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the method it would be necessary to make an explicit cast.

In this case it would be more interesting to leave your Meow() method more generic for other possible classes that could implement it:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Eat();
    void Speak();
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{  
    public void Eat() {  }

    public string Speak()
    {
        return "meow";
    }   
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{  
    public void Eat() {  }

    public string Speak()
    {
        return "au";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents on this topic is that it's true that you need to depend on abstractions (i.e. *interfaces*) rather than implementations.

BTW, doesn't this going too far? There's no need to define an interface for any class within your object model. Usually you define interfaces if you need to accept certain objects fulfilling a given contract.

For example, I wouldn't define `IAnimal` or `ICat` interfaces. Probably I would define an abstract class `Animal` and just a concrete class `Cat`.

If for some reason I need to accept living beings in some API that could *eat* I would define an interface like this:

```
public interface IFeedable
{
      void Feed(Food food);
}
```

and if a living being can *talk*:

```
public interface ITalkative
{
     void Talk(Food food);
}
```

Unless there's no feature/property/behavior that could be exclusive to animals, I would leave these interfaces *as is*.

```
public abstract class Animal : ITalkative, IFeedable
{
     public Animal(AudioPlayer audioPlayer)
     {
          AudioPlayer = audioPlayer;
     }

     private AudioPlayer AudioPlayer { get; }

     public abstract void Feed(Food food);

     public void Talk()
     {
           // Probably you would want to load an animal sound library
           // here, and later pass the audio player with the sound library
           // already loaded
           OnTalk(AudioPlayer.LoadLibrary("animals"));
     }

     protected abstract void OnTalk(AudioLibrary audioLibrary);
}

public sealed class Cat : Animal
{
      public Cat(AudioPlayer audioPlayer) : base(audioPlayer) 
      {
      }

      public override void Feed(Food food)
      {
           if(food is Vegetable)
           {
                throw new NotSupportedException("MeeEEEEooW (=O ò.ó)=O!!");
           }
           else if(food is Meat)
           {
               // Proceed to eat this meat!
           }
      }

      protected override void OnTalk(AudioLibrary audioLibrary)
      {
            audioLibrary.Play("sweet-cat");
      }
}
```

And if somewhere you need to make an object to talk:

```
ITalkative talkative = some as ITalkative;

if(talkative != null)
{
    talkative.Talk();
}
```

Or if you need to feed the object:

```
IFeedable feedable = some as IFeedable;

if(feedable != null)
{
    feedable.Feed(new Vegetable());
}
```

As you can see, you don't define interfaces for everything, but just for those things that you need to handle inside some API and you don't care who can do some actions and/or own some data, but you just care about the object can do or exposes certain behaviors and data respectively.